# Is 800x480 pixels screen resolution on a 7" screen bad?

Tags: resolution

I am interested in buying a 7 inches tablet that it has 800x480 pixels screen resolution.

This gave me a question, how can I know/see how a the resolution looks like? Are there any screen resolution simulators available?

Thank you

Comment: What are you actually asking? You are aware of different DPI screens?

Comment: @DanielBeck "Off topic" with more than 1k views ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to go to a local computer or electronics retailer and look at their different devices for yourself.

There really isn't a way to simulate the resolution / DPI etc. because for most people, what is best is subjective to that individual. It's especially tricky when comparing "true" pixels like computer screens to AMOLED screens on mobile devices (tablets, phones, etc.) or large-screen LCD or LED tv's. The physical pixels are different in each case and I recommend 100% looking for yourself to find what you think is most comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an image of 800*480 pixels and then zoom in/out until it has the same size as a 7" screen. Though, like Josh says, it's not a real representation of the screen

I have done some math, and your screen would be 6"x3.6" or 9,15x15,25cm, giving a resolution of 133,28 PPI or 52,472 PPcm. That's pretty dense, considering a computer screen normally has 96PPI.